# How to compute the same period effect for two groups in r

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to compute the following model:

```
lm(wage ~ college * age + woman + yr_edu + yr_entry + factor(yr_survey), data = data)
```

where **college** is a dummy variable coded 1 for those college educated, **yr_edu** is a variable for the years of education in college, **yr_entry** is the year of entry to the college, and **yr_survey** is the survey year. 
I aim to compare the wage level of those college educated and not through the above model. Since it is subject to the collinearity because **yr_entry = yr_survey - yr_edu**, I want to restrict the period effect (of the **yr_survey**) for the educated and not educated to be the same. 
Meaning that, the period effect estimated from those who did not get the college education and used to calculate the coefficients for other variables included in the model.
So far I have used the code specified above for the estimation, but I am confused if the results are giving me the period effect for both of the groups, not the calculation just from no-education group. Any ideas on solving the problem? 
Also, I would like to apply this on a random-effects model:

```
plm(wage ~ college * age + woman + yr_edu + yr_entry + factor(yr_survey),
    data = data, index = ("id, "year"), model = "random")
```

Any idea on how to fix these? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If both groups are part of data, you''l get the overall effect of each variable. Since `yr_survey` is continuously scaled, there is no need to use random effects.

Comment: @danlooo Thanks for the comment! Could you give me any idea on how to code it to get the effect of `yr_survey` for the no education group and use the same effect for the pooled data?

Answer (score 0):

Lets model the continous outcome displacement on cars of two groups (VW or not) by adjusting for effects of cylinders and time (year):

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <-
  mpg %>%
  transmute(
    group = ifelse(manufacturer %in% c("volkswagen", "audi"), "vw", "other"),
    displ,
    cyl,
    year
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(c("cyl", "displ"), scale)

# vw cars are associated to have less cylinders and less displacement
qplot(cyl, displ, color = group, data = data)
```

[image]

```r
lm(displ ~ group + cyl + year, data = data) %>%
  summary() 
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = displ ~ group + cyl + year, data = data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.84630 -0.29200  0.04977  0.20457  1.47538 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) -14.384902  10.103808  -1.424    0.156    
#> groupvw      -0.341378   0.060255  -5.666 4.36e-08 ***
#> cyl           0.883520   0.023943  36.901  < 2e-16 ***
#> year          0.007213   0.005043   1.430    0.154    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.3445 on 230 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8829, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8813 
#> F-statistic: 577.8 on 3 and 230 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Time does not significantly influence displacement.
The displacement of VW cars are 0.34 standard deviations lower on average.
Incerasing the number of cylinders by one standard deviation will increase the displacement by 0.88 standard deviations on average if all other factors will kept constant.

Looking at averages per group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(manufacturer %in% c("volkswagen", "audi"), "vw", "other")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mean_displ = mean(displ))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   group mean_displ
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 other       3.73
#> 2 vw          2.37
```